# Hint on how to find $\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am almost sure that this would have been asked before, but how can one find
$$
\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} dx?
$$
If I had a $x^2 - 1$ in the denominator, then I could factor into $(x-1)(x+1)$ and use partial fractions. But here I have an irreducible $1+x^2$.

I am sure that this question has already been answered, but I don't want to see a full solution. I was hoping that I could get **just a hint**.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, so you should manage to know $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx$.

Comment: "You should manage know..." is an odd construction. How should he manage to know it if he doesn't know it yet? @MonkeyKing

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Well perhaps OP didn't think of this strategy, or perhaps s/he can't integrate this term. I am not so sure which part s/he is having problem.

Comment: I'm just not sure what "you should manage to know" means. It seems like an implication - if the OP doesn't know this, and can't figure it out, he is somehow failing. A less obtuse sentence would be "and you might already know ..."

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Sorry I did not know that, I just picked the most fancy expression I can think of. =( English is not my native language. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I'd add that as a rule rational functions should be expanded such, for integration: if the degree of the numerator is $\geq$ the degree of the denominator, use polynomial long division (dividing the numerator by the denominator). The answers given are doing just that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, just a hint: $$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\,{\rm d}x = \int 1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,{\rm d}x,$$ and the last one is immediate.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks. I will accept when I can.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$x^2 = x^2 + 1 - 1         $$
or you could try this substitution:
$$x = \tan(\theta)$$